# Config Parameters on Red Hat enterprise

Tags: linux, documentation, redhat

I'm doing an homework for my college, and i'm trying to find the parameters used in kernel compilation ON redhat.

I need to know about process, memory management, scheduling, file system and security, but i cant find anything on redhat documentation(what i found was too brief).

Comment: have you asked this question on (Unix&Linux) -- you may get a quicker answer -- http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Tasos thanks, i didnt know that have a unix and linux community here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More information was found at this : https://unix.stackexchange.com/